# Is there a reason why setting the metadata and image URI to Google Storage doesn't work with explorers?

Tags: metaplex, explorers

I am minting an [NFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-fungible_token#Description) and setting the metadata and image URI to public storage buckets on [Google Cloud Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform) (GCP). I am able to view the image and metadata on my wallet, but only x-ray explorer supports it.

I can't view the image on the explorer, solscan or solanaFM.

Here is the token on XRAY: https://xray.helius.xyz/token/96prF4jTGCMdEPnpMEc9mjRrR3qG3dL9KoWwN2ZrRGjD?network=devnet

Comment: What happens when you view the browser console when you try and view one? Can you comment the NFT Id here? :)

Comment: @TonyBoyle here is the NFT 96prF4jTGCMdEPnpMEc9mjRrR3qG3dL9KoWwN2ZrRGjD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) error from your Google Cloud Storage. If you check the network tab when you load up sol-scan or the other NFT viewers, you'll see it fails to fetching your JSON metadata, which in turn holds your image URI.

https://solscan.io/token/96prF4jTGCMdEPnpMEc9mjRrR3qG3dL9KoWwN2ZrRGjD?cluster=devnet#metadata

Here’s the documentation for Google CORS: *[Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin)*

You'll most likely have to edit the CORS settings for your bucket: *[Set bucket CORS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-cors)*